# dio BaseOptions connectTimeout receiveTimeout doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

My connectTimeout and receiveTimeouts don't work. Here is my code:

```
BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: 
        'http://localhost:5000/api',
    connectTimeout: 5000,
    receiveTimeout: 3000,
    responseType: ResponseType.plain);

Dio myDio = new Dio(options);

// api file
      final response = await myDio.get('/test');

// on the backend in Node.js, i delay my response with:
        setTimeout(function () { res.status(201).json(result) }, 50000)
```

However, this does not work. What is interesting however, is that if I do this it works:

```
myDio.options.connectTimeout = 5000; 
myDio.options.receiveTimeout = 3000;

final response = await myDio.get('/test');
```

I don't really want to do this, since I have many api calls and I want my `myDio` instance to take care of all the timeouts. Any idea how to get around this, or what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a utility class that gives you a "pre-configured" Dio object, something along these lines:

```
class WebUtil {

    static Dio createDio() {
    var dio = Dio(
        BaseOptions(
            baseUrl: "${AppSettings.webServiceUrl}/api/",
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json",
            }
        )
    );
    dio.options.connectTimeout = 5000;
    dio.options.receiveTimeout = 3000;
    return dio;
  }
}

  // Nothing to do with your question, just a simple helper method to parse Dio exceptions:
  static String getUserExceptionMessage(DioError dioError) {
    return '${dioError.response.statusCode}: ${dioError.response.statusMessage}.\nURL: ${dioError.request.path}';
  }
}
```

To use:

```
Response response = await WebUtil.createDio().get("some-call");
```